# How can I place a ProgressBar in Android using Cocos 2d?

Tags: opengl, android, cocos2d

I want to place a horizontal progress bar in my Android application and I want to change its progress color. I used the following code, but the progress bar is not being displayed.

```
CCProgressTimer progressBar = CCProgressTimer.progress("progressbar.png");
progressBar.setType(kCCProgressTimerTypeHorizontalBarLR);
progressBar.setScale(5);
progressBar.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(0, 0));
progressBar.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(0,0));
addChild(progressBar);
```

Comment: are you sure it's not behind some other object?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a CCProgressFromTo action into your `progressBar`, then show `progressBar`.